# bootstrap 4 and laravel 5.6 not showing error under input field

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I am using laravel 5.6 and have the follwing in blade file:

```
<form method="POST" action="/review">
                    @csrf
                    {{ $errors->first('nickname') }}

                    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{ request()->route('id') }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="nickname">nickname:</label>
                      <input type="text" name="nickname" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('nickname') ? 'is-ivalid' : ''}}" id="nickname">
                      @if($errors->has('nickname'))
                      <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('nickname') }}</strong>
                      </div>
                      @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="review">comment:</label>
                      <textarea name="review" class="form-control"></textarea>
                      @if($errors->has('review'))
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('review') }}</strong>
                      </span>
                      @endif
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </form>
```

as you see in the third line I added {{$errors->first('nickname')}} just to make sure it has output and it does but just not showing the output under the input field.
how to solve this? why it happened?

Comment: Let's see your controller function. Are you returning with `withErrors()`?

Comment: You have a typo in `{{ $errors->has('nickname') ? 'is-ivalid' : ''}}` should be `is-invalid`.

Comment: @thefallen that was exactly the error. do you care to write it in answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `{{ $errors->has('nickname') ? 'is-ivalid' : ''}}` should be `is-invalid`.